# OData Query: Getting several rows based on a column criteria

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

I have a table that holds an attribute field and its corresponding value. For an instance several attributes are applicable, and I would like to return a specific set of attributes for this instance.

```
    |Attribute|Value|
    ----------
    | A       | 1   |
    ----------
    | B       | 2   |
    ----------
    | C       | 3   |
    ----------
```

How can I query with Odata to get attribute A and C and their corresponding values?

As of now I'm only able to get a single row with `$filter=endswith(Attribute, 'A')`.

Comment: That worked, thanks :) If you reply as answer I can mark that as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add more filters with `or` operator on ODATA query, something like this:

```
$filter=(endswith(Attribute, 'A') or endswith(Attribute, 'C'))
```

Comment: The key element for me here was to surround the hole query with () and their sub-queries by their own ()'s.